# How to make my function take less time in python?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to do this problem:

https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/blocks-pyramid-def-pyramidblocks-n-m-h-pyramid-structure-although-ancient-mesoamerican-fam-q38542637

This is my code:

```
def pyramid_blocks(n, m, h):
    return sum((n+i)*(m+i) for i in range(h))
```

But the problem is that whenever I try to test it, it tells me that it is too slow, so is there a way to make it take less time? I also tried to do it with lists, but with that too it takes too much time.

```
def pyramid_blocks(n, m, h):
    return sum((n+i)*(m+i) for i in range(h))
```

```
def pyramid_blocks(n, m, h):
    r=[]
    t=[]
    mlp=[]
    for i in range(h):
        r.append(n+i)
        t.append(m+i)
    for i, j in zip(r,t):
        mlp.append(i*j)
    return sum(mlp)
```

Comment: You should be able to use discrete math and combinatorics to come up with an analytical closed form formula for the result, which will enable you to compute the results much faster. (Or at least, that's what it says on the question page.)

Comment: @JackTaylor yeah I saw that too, but what type of discrete math? boolean algebra? p and q?? can you give me a hint of where I should start beside pf the discrete math part?

Comment: The [sum of squares](https://www.cuemath.com/algebra/sum-of-squares/) formula is roughly the same idea. That might give you a starting point.

Comment: Think about how you can express the count as a single expression. Maybe start by setting `m=1` and draw it up on a piece of paper.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%28%28n%2Bi%29%28m%2Bi%29+for+i+in+0...h-1%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of math can help:
[here we use a symbolic calculator to get the equation for the blocks in the pyramid using a sigma sum of (n+count)*(m+count) from count = 0 to count = h-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMfJR.png)

Then we just paste the equation into code (the double slash // is just to use integer division instead of float division):

```
def count_blocks(n,m,h):
    return (2*(h**3)+3*(h**2)*m+3*(h**2)*n+6*h*m*n-3*(h**2)-3*h*m-3*h*n+h)//6
```

Edit: This also outputs the correct result of 10497605327499753 for n,m,h = (2123377, 2026271, 2437)

Answer (score 0):

You should use math to understand the components that are part of the answer. you need to calculate sum of all numbers until h, denote `s`, and the sum of all squares `1^2+2^2+3+2+...` denotes `sum_power`
it comes down to: `h*m*n + s*n + s*m + sum_power`

this is a working solution:

```
import time


def pyramid_blocks(n, m, h):
    return sum((n+i)*(m+i) for i in range(h))


def efficient_pyramid_blocks(n, m, h):
    s = (h-1)*h//2
    sum_power = (h-1)*h*(2*(h-1)+1)//6
    return h*n*m + s*(n+m) + sum_power


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n, m, h = 2123377, 2026271, 2437
    start = time.time()
    print(pyramid_blocks(n, m, h))
    print(time.time()-start)
    start = time.time()
    print(efficient_pyramid_blocks(n, m, h))
    print(time.time() - start)
```

and the output is:

```
333723479800000
0.016993045806884766
333723479800000
1.2159347534179688e-05
```

Comment: It doesnt work, for (2123377, 2026271, 2437) it is supposed to return 10497605327499753 but it returned 10497605327499754, I think there is a way to do it without using /6 because it looks like when we do divided by 6 the answer is off by 1.

Comment: I edited my answer, a casting to int on the division product seems to solve this issue. @sfreg